# Artifactory repository replication with same ArtifactoryPro license

Tags: artifactory

My organization is in the process of deploying Artifactory for use by development teams. I want to know is it possible to set up Push or pull repository replication with one ArtifactoryPro license ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use replication from one instance of artifactory to the other if they have the same licence.